# В чем отличия метода от функции?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Хотелось бы узнать о различиях между методом (`{method(){}}`) и функцией (`{function: function(){}}`) - как по смыслу, так и технически. Желательно не выдержку из спеки (в конце можно и её), а более человеческим языком.

Как частный вопрос: почему метод не получается использовать в роли конструктора?

```js
function f(){}
let obj = {
  f(){}
};

console.info(new f());     // {}
console.info(new obj.f()); // TypeError: obj.f is not a constructor
```

Comment: В объекте метод объявляется так `f: function(){}`

Comment: @Duoxx, оба примера синтаксически верны

Comment: @Duoxx, кажется кто-то проспал ES6...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разница между "методом" и "функцией" в JS исключительно в синтаксисе. Аналогично с "классом" и "прототипом".

Просто к ES6 разрабы языка решили окончательно признать, что прототипы никому даром не нужны ни под каким соусом (расширения стандартных классов сообщество объявило вселенским злом, а выкрутасы с прототипами мимо классического ООПа напрочь убивают хитроумные оптимизации во всех жабоскриптовых движках), поэтому следующее поколение жабоскриптеров может писать "классы", "методы", "конструкторы", а про прототипы вспоминать на лекциях "продвинутый жабоскрипт, или, мама, я еду без рук!"

---

Вопсче, традиционно считается, что функция — это нечто, что существует отдельно от всего, принимает параметры и возвращает результат; метод — это нечто, что прибито гвоздями к конкретному объекту, на деле принимает объект первым аргументом явно или неявно, а так от функции мало отличается; и всякие Вирты ещё отделяют процедуры, которые что-то делают, временами что-то принимают, но ничего не возвращают.

В мире жабоскрипта этого всего не существует: this есть везде, глобальные функции являются методами глобального объекта (в браузерах window), функции всегда что-то возвращают (если ничего не вернуть явно, undefined вернут за вас). В других языках стройное разделение портят статические глобальные методы, методы-расширения и прочее, что помножает всякую классификацию на ноль.

Внутри все эту функции-методы-процедуры выглядят абсолютно одинаково: пушнули позицию, джампнулись, что-то сделали, попнули, вернулись.

Comment: Почему неправильный?

Comment: Ну неверно же...

Answer (score 1):

Функция и сама по себе и как свойство объекта - это одна и та же сущность, «технически» не отличается ничем. Только «идейно»: метод объекта предполагается использовать для одних целей, а «отдельную» функцию - для других. Когда что использовать - вопрос архитектуры.

Невозможность вызвать метод объекта с оператором **new** связана с тем, что оператор **new** и операция вызова метода (точка .) не могут «поделить» между собой передаваемое в функцию значение **this**. Вызов метода должен передать в качестве **this** ссылку на объект, из которого совершается вызов, а оператор **new** должен неявно передать в качестве **this** пустой объект, который функция могла бы заполнить и вернуть в качестве нового объекта. Эта коллизия и есть причина, почему такой вызов не работает.